# Why are two different BLE adapters show different devices when scanning?

Tags: bluetooth, ibeacon, archlinux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I have two boards:
Board 1: PixiePro running Arch Linux, Bluez 5.4 | Onboard Bluetooth Adapter
Board 2: Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, Bluez 5.39 | USB Bluetooth Dongle

While using `hcitool` to scan for BLE devices (iBeacon) on Board 1, I only receive the address of a single device (pic below).

```
AC:BC:32:72:8C:6B
```

I have more than 10 iBeacons that the adapter should be finding. I've tried the following techniques:

Start `hcitool lescan`, removing duplicates

```
sudo hcitool lescan --duplicates
```

[image: single BLE device detected on Board 1 (PixiePro)]

Start `hcitool lescan` process & read data from `hcidump`

```
sudo hcitool lescan --duplicates 1>/dev/null &
sudo hcidump --raw
```

[image: single BLE device detected on Board 1, <code>hcidump</code> output]

These both just show one or two different mac addresses. There should be several different mac addresses for the various iBeacons near me.

Here is output by Board 2 using a USB bluetooth dongle for comparison:

```
sudo hcitool lescan
```

[image: basic <code>hcitool lescan</code> in same physical location, from Board 2]

As you can see, there are quite a few different devices, some of which are immediately identifiable as Kontakt iBeacons. Note: most of the beacons around me are not Kontakt iBeacons

Is there a setting I'm missing or need to enable when using `hcitool lescan`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to help you with this one.

It seems that there is something wrong **with your PixiePro device**, however information you’ve provided is not enough to diagnose the issue.

It could be a problem with either the device itself, or Bluez stack, or, simply because the devices are out of the detectable range of the PixiePro device.

**In order to debug your issue you may try to do the following:**

- First of all **check mac-addresses, uuid, major and minor values** of
  your devices. Usually you may find this information on the web-portal
  of your iBeacon vendor;
- **Ensure that all of the devices are turned on and working.** The simplest way
  is to check whether they are detected by a mobile phone. You may
  install [free iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/beacon-scan/id1011834079?mt=8]%20or%20%20%20%20Android[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.flurp.beaconscanner.app) or [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.flurp.beaconscanner.app) application. You should be able to detect all of your devices. Also check the RSSI values of every iBeacon device. Please note that values will vary even though they can be at the same distance from the phone to the iBeacon. However, the behavior, while you are moving them further or closer to the receiving device, should be clearly recognized by the mobile application;
- Once you are 100% sure that all of the iBeacon devices are
  working properly, **you should be able to detect the mac-addresses on
  your board devices.** To do this, I’d recommend to run the `hcitool` in
  the first terminal window and the `hcidump` tool in the second
  without any additional parameters. Unlike the `hcitool` command it
  will also output the RSSI values of captured packets like this:

  ```
  HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 42 
  LE Advertising Report 
  ADV_NONCONN_IND - Non connectable undirected advertising (3) 
  bdaddr 02:AB:26:D4:9A:EE (Public) 
  Flags: 0x1a 
  Unknown type 0xff with 25 bytes data 
  RSSI: -72
  ```

**These values will help you to compare the behavior of scanning on different devices.** DON’T expect them to be equal everywhere, these are simply relative values. Now try to move each of your devices close to your receiving board(s) and you should be able to see its mac-address in the output of the `hcidump` tool.

- In this case if you still don’t see your iBeacon devices then for
  sure **there is an issue somewhere in your boards.** It could be either
  hardware or software. This is where I’d recommend:

  1. Install the
     latest firmware, which may fix bugs in the BLE stack
     implementation.
  2. If this approach doesn’t help - then it means that the
     issue lies somewhere in the hardware and, therefore, the only thing you
     can do is to replace your board device.

Good luck!

If any questions, feel free to ask!